# Decimal Parse Issue

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

The string value is `"90-"`. Why does the decimal parse it as `"-90"` but `double` throws a `FormatException`?

```
var inputValue= "90-";
Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(inputValue));
Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(inputValue));
```

Comment: Do you mean to have `.TryParse` in your code sample?

Comment: nice question for `Eric Lippert`

Comment: They just pass different defaults to the number parser. The `decimal` one is configured to look for common money formats and the `double` one isn't.

Comment: Fell across this today with Int32.Parse - it throws as I'd expect, but Decimal.Parse doesn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `decimal.Parse(string s)` overload, by default, is called with [NumberStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) `NumberStyles.Number` which is defined as:

> Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite,
>   AllowLeadingSign, **AllowTrailingSign**, AllowDecimalPoint, and
>   AllowThousands styles are used. This is a composite number style.

Note that `AllowTrailingSign` is included.  If you wish to customize the behaviour then you should explicitly call the overload that allows you to specify a number style and tailor it to your needs.

Answer (score 8):

The implementation is different between the two:

```
public static double Parse(String s) {
    return Parse(s, NumberStyles.Float| NumberStyles.AllowThousands, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}

public static Decimal Parse(String s) {
    return Number.ParseDecimal(s, NumberStyles.Number, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

where

```
NumberStyles.Float     = AllowLeadingWhite | AllowTrailingWhite | AllowLeadingSign | 
                         AllowDecimalPoint | AllowExponent,

NumberStyles.Number    = AllowLeadingWhite | AllowTrailingWhite | AllowLeadingSign | AllowTrailingSign |
                         AllowDecimalPoint | AllowThousands
```

So `decimal.Parse` allows *trailing* signs but `double.Parse` does not.

Looks like the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN is inaccurate:

> Parameter s contains a number of the form:
>
> [ws][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][ws]

It should indicate that a *trailing* sign is valid as well.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting, it seems that by default, `decimal` and `double` use different number styles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx

> Parameter s is interpreted using the NumberStyles.Number style. This means that white space and thousands separators are allowed but currency symbols are not.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The s parameter is interpreted using a combination of the NumberStyles.Float and NumberStyles.AllowThousands flags. This means that white space and thousands separators are allowed, for example, while currency symbols are not.

It's not immediately obvious from those descriptions, but if you look it up, `NumberStyles.Number` allows trailing sign:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx

> Indicates that the AllowLeadingWhite, AllowTrailingWhite, AllowLeadingSign, AllowTrailingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, and AllowThousands styles are used. This is a composite number style.

Presumably the difference in the defaults is because `decimal` is often used for currency calculations.

Of course, in both cases you can supply your own number format specifying exactly what you do and don't want to accept so you can make them consistent for your own use.